# Multiple Browser Profiles for Multiple (Concurrent) Test Execution?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, testng

Multiple Browser Profiles for Multiple (Concurrent) Test Execution?

1. Is this even possible?
2. For example I can execute two tests at the same time but when two tests open at the same time within the same browser they seem to share the same cookies.
3. Please find my main Browser factory class listed below, can anyone advise the best way to alter my code, or settings required which will enable me to meet my objective?

Thanks for your help

```
public class BrowserFactory implements ISuiteListener {
    private static WebDriver webdriver;

    public static WebDriver getDriver() throws Exception {
        try {
            Properties p = new Properties();
            FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(Constant.CONFIG_PROPERTIES_DIRECTORY);
            p.load(fi);

            String browserName = p.getProperty("browser");
            switch (browserName) {

            //firefox setup
            case "firefox":
                if (null == webdriver) {
                    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", Constant.GECKO_DRIVER_DIRECTORY);
                    webdriver = new FirefoxDriver();
                }
                break;

           //chrome setup
            case "chrome":
                if (null == webdriver) {
                    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", Constant.CHROME_DRIVER_DIRECTORY);
                    DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
                    LoggingPreferences logPrefs = new LoggingPreferences();
                    logPrefs.enable(LogType.BROWSER, Level.ALL);
                    caps.setCapability(CapabilityType.LOGGING_PREFS, logPrefs);
                    webdriver = new ChromeDriver(caps);
                }
                break;

           //IE setup   
            case "ie":
                if (null == webdriver) {
                    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", Constant.IE_DRIVER_DIRECTORY);
                    webdriver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
                }
                break;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Unable to load browser! - Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return webdriver;
    }



    @AfterClass
    public void quitDriver() throws Exception {
        if (null != webdriver) {
            getDriver().manage().deleteAllCookies();
            webdriver.quit();
            webdriver = null;
        }

        // Output the time when a test class has ended
        String tempTimeEndClass = new SimpleDateFormat("hh.mm.ss").format(new Date());
        System.out.println("\nTEST CLASS END TIME: " + tempTimeEndClass);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, of course it is possible!
2. They share the same cookies because the instance of the WebDriver you are creating is static, trying removing the static modifier so on every launch of the webdriver you get a unique instance.

> public webdriver driver; public WebDriver getDriver() throws Exception
>   { }

If the above isn't enough and you want to do additional things with the profiles; just pass it as a parameter via xml or as a String var in the method:

```
currentProfile = "user-data-dir=/path/to/your/custom/profile";
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments(currentProfile);
```

*Again, careful here currentProfile needs to be an instance variable not a static one!*

Best of luck!

Comment: sorry just another question, if i remove the static from the webdriver instance and then setup one profile for the tests to share, it shouldnt conflict with cookies? even if all sharing the same profile?

thanks again

Comment: Correct Gbru, same profile shouldn't conflict with cookies.

Comment: Yourself as well, np glad if I was of some help! :)

Comment: sorry dont mean to pepper you with comments, but one last question :] when you get time, do you know why if i remove the static word from the local variable:private static WebDriver webdriver, it asks me to change the other webdriver instances inside the class to static, thanks :]

Comment: Always better when you fix it yourself; as you understand how it works! ;)